# Multiple File Upload Only takes last file in Scala/Play

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am using play framework 2.1.x with Scala,

I would like to upload many files but only my last input stays as input.

I have the following input in my template:

```
<input id="musicFile" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="file" onchange="check_file()" name="file" accept="audio/*" multiple />
```

And in the Controller, I try to get the file with

```
 val music_files = request.body.files.toArray;
 music_files.foreach(file =>
```

However even if I select multiple files, only the last one is stored in `music_files`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an example: when i first  browsed 3 files and then 1 browsed would get  1 browsed files as the last file.

Comment: try to change attribute `name` to `"name=file[]"` which indicates that file is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side part looks fine, so I assume your client side is only uploading the last file. You can verify this with the debugging tools of your browser, for example in Chrome:

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer console and go to `Network`.
- Perform the action that triggers the upload of the files.
- You should see the `POST` request and should also see if there are multiple files attached or a single one.

I was very successful in using [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) for the client side part of my application, which works well for multiple files.